# How to verify string something like this (For eg: 27˚) in Swift.The value is random?

Tags: regex, xcode, swift5

As we know to represent ˚ in swift (\u{00B0}) is the value. but here want a regex to validate data like 27˚ or 15˚. How to achieve in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly use it in regex like this

```swift
let str = "37 Hello World 37\u{00B0}"
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]+\u{00B0}")
let match = regex.firstMatch(in: str, options: [], range: range)
print(match?.range)
```

```
Optional({15, 3})
```

if you want match both `\u{00B0}` and `˚`,you can write `(\u{00B0}|˚)` in regex

```swift
let str = "37 Hello World 37\u{00B0} 37˚"
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]+(\u{00B0}|˚)")

let matches = regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: range)

for match in matches {
    print(match.range)
}
```